# Android Studio - How to avoidOutOfMemoryError when rotating images

Tags: android, image, error-handling, out-of-memory

How can I avoid the OutOfMemoryError when I am rotating images in most simplest form. I am very new to Android Studio and Java. This is the static method of rotation of images

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation, Context context) {

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                break;
            default:
                return bitmap;
        }
        try {
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2, matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return bmRotated;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error:"  + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your use-case is but you can get simple rotation without resorting to  a matrix. It is fairly easy to run out of memory with large bitmaps.

This on the other hand, will rotate any given imageview by some random amount from 0 to 360 degrees, with fairly low overhead:

```
        display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.someview);
        int randomRot;
        Random rand = new Random();
        randomRot=rand.nextInt(360);
        display.setRotation((float) randomRot);
```

Comment: How can I rotate a portrait image into landscape? Landscape into portrait?

Answer (score 0):

yourImageView.setRotation(angle) with API>=11